# Detecting images containing only black pixels

Tags: images

I am looking for a method for detecting if an image contains only black pixels. When I say method I mean an existing command line tool. I could write up something myself but I'm sure something probably exists already.

Comment: Do you want to detect exact black pictures RGB(0,0,0), or also dark pictures like ones with too short exposure?

Answer (score 2):

I bet that [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is what you want.  In fact, there's [an Imagemagick forum entry](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17111) that probably fits your needs.